# Hover in Selenium does not work

Tags: selenium

This is not really question, but just sharing my experience.
I am testing a page containing charts. Whenever a hover action by mouse is done, it shows small hint next to it. This work perfectly interacting with the element manually. The problem happens when trying to hover over element from Selenium.

I tested it with the following code, but it did not work

```
new Actions(getDriver()).moveToElement(graphElement).build().perform();
```

It only works if the folowing code is executed prior to using Actions

```
graphElement.click();
```

Even though the Actions click() method does not work. It really needs to be clicked through WebElement.click() and then use Actions...

Does anyone have similar experience with this behaviour? Why does the element should be clicked on before the Actions can work?
Because it is in contrary with the flow. Why anyone would start with clicking on the element to check that some message is displayed on hover action?

JS workaround (hover) does not help as well.

Thanks for your posts.

Comment: Try: Actions(getDriver()).moveToElement(graphElement).build().perform();

Comment: Perhaps it's related to the current focus. I don't know what you tried but it's possible you need to first make sure the element or parent is focused before you can perform a hover/click action.

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Deepan: ..build().perform().. is not working as well.
Chuk Ultima: Do you think to focus on parent <div> to be able to focus on the nested child? Then why does the WebElement.click() work?

Comment: Found that Actions is useless in this case. If I click on the element and then click again, it stays focused, so hover is executed. I tried to focus parent sub parent, etc. and no successes. I see that html code is different if I want to see Page source code. It means that code is perhaps generated dynamically by JS. I am screwed.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched and found very neat solution.
Using the following code solved that problem with focus.

```
graphElement.sendKeys("");
```

so the final version

```
graphElement.sendKeys("");
new Actions(getDriver()).moveToElement(graphElement).build().perform();
```